# Call java class function in FTL - Apache

Tags: javascript, java, html

I am trying to call a java class function in a ftl file of the same project:
Class:

```
public class ShoppingCart<statics> implements Iterable<ShoppingCartItem>{

public String testfct(){
return "Hello";
}

}
```

In the ftl file I want to call this function by using:

```
<fieldset>
    ${testfct}
</fieldset>
```

This doesn't work :-(